# Scala - How to send a failing response in case of an exception using Futures

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, concurrency, future

I'm working on an endpoint that I want to be non-blocking. The purpose of this endpoint is very simple i.e. write a document to a Mongo store. I'm using the official [MongoDB Scala Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/) in a Play 2.5.x app.

My understanding is that MongoDB supports Futures using the `toFuture()` method. [Source](http://rosslawley.co.uk/mongodb-scala-driver-released/)

The issue is that the handling method in my controller expects to resolve to the type `Future[Result]`. However, the `onComplete` callback  (or other callback functions) only return the type `Unit`, resulting in a compilation error. Are there any alternative patterns that are being used for these situations? What are my options?

Note - I understand that Play will catch the exception in case of failure to write and throw a 500 automatically. But in this case I want to handle it manually

```
class WriteController extends Controller {

  def writeSingleEvent = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val mongo = mongoService.getMongoClient() // my mongoservice
    val database_name: String = request.getQueryString("database").getOrElse("")
    val collection_name: String = request.getQueryString("collection").getOrElse("")

    if (database_name == "" || collection_name == "") {
      Future(BadRequest("Must specify database and collection names"))
    } else {
      val database = mongo.getDatabase(database_name)
      val collection = database.getCollection(collection_name)

      val body = request.body.asJson.get.toString
      val bsondocument = BsonDocument.apply(body)
      val document = Document(bsondocument)

      val insertFuture = collection.insertOne(document).toFuture()
      insertFuture.onComplete {
        case Success(_) => Future(Ok("Inserted"))
        case Failure(_) => Future(InternalServerError)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this instead of `onComplete`. `onComplete` is used for performing any side-effecting operations.

```
insertFuture
   .map(_ => Ok("Inserted"))
   .recover({case _ => InternalServerError})
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on you are trying to do, you are probably looking for the [`transform`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/concurrent/Future.html#transform[S](s:T=%3ES,f:Throwable=%3EThrowable)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) method:

```
val res = insertFuture.transform(_ => Ok("Inserted"), _ => InternalServerError)
```

Comment: Results in two errors. First - type mismatch on `InternalServerError`, says type Throwable is required. Also that the overall function should be returning type `FutureResult]` and not `Unit`